# Problem with sablecc on production rule of the form prod = (expr | expr')*

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, computer-science, sablecc

```
Productions
    program = cls*;
    cls = clsdef name openbrace clsdata closingbrace;
    clsdata = (clsfield|clsmethod)*;
    clsfield = [variabletype]:name [variablename]:name semi;
    clsmethod = [returntype]:name [methodname]:name openmethodbrace closingmethodbrace openbrace closingbrace;
```

The problem resides in

```
clsdata = (clsfield|clsmethod)*;
```

If I set `clsdata` to

```
clsdata = clsfield*;
```

or to

```
clsdata = clsmethod*;
```

it works fine, though, as you can imagine, it doesn't mean the same thing as what I intended it to. I want a class to allow for both methods and fields (in no specific order!).

So my question is in how should I define `clsdata` so that I don't get errors. I can think of recursive alternatives, but I'd like to keep this as clean as possible!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> clsdata = (clsfield|clsmethod)*;

SableCC has an EBNF *like* syntax, but does not support this type of grammar rule. As you've already done, the non-terminal alternatives `clsfield` and `clsmethod` need be refractored into their own production.

> yet I am not sure this is the best way to do this

If you look at any of the [SableeCC example grammars](http://sablecc.sourceforge.net/grammars.html) you'll see that is the standard way of defining 'class members'. Although you could perhaps simplify your grammar by removing `clsmembers`:

```
Productions
    program = cls*;
    cls = clsdef name openbrace clsmember* closingbrace;
    clsmember = {clsfield} clsfield | {clsmethod} clsmethod;
    clsfield = [variabletype]:name [variablename]:name semi;
    clsmethod = [returntype]:name [methodname]:name openmethodbrace closingmethodbrace openbrace closingbrace
```

Answer (score -1):

This works:

```
Productions
    program = cls*;
    cls = clsdef name openbrace clsmembers closingbrace;
    clsmembers = clsmember*;
    clsmember = {clsfield} clsfield | {clsmethod} clsmethod;
    clsfield = [variabletype]:name [variablename]:name semi;
    clsmethod = [returntype]:name [methodname]:name openmethodbrace closingmethodbrace openbrace closingbrace;
```

yet I am not sure this is the best way to do this. I welcome other approaches!